# @import variables for all scss files

Tags: sass

in my template.scss on top

```scss
@import "variables";
@import "reset";
```

but I get errors on reset.scss

```bash
Libsass: Error: Undefined variable: "$baseFontSize".
on line 13 of .../sass/reset.scss
>>          font-size:$baseFontSize;
```

because it doesn't know variables.scss . I had never that problem before with less

variables.scss is my first @import file it should work across all other .scss imported

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are probably inside a ruleset (selector block) and are thus [lexically scoped](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-variable-scope-in-sass--cms-23498). Therefore they are not available outside of said block. To circumvent you should either define all variables on the root level of your `variables.scss` or add the `!global` modifier to your variables.

```
$baseFontSize: 12px !global;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for `$baseFontSize` in your reset file, if present then follow the following:

`@import` takes a filename to import. By default, it looks for a Sass file to import directly, but there are a few circumstances under which it will compile to a CSS `@import` rule:

- If the filename begins with `http://`.
- If the filename is a `url()`.
- If the `@import` has any media queries.

If none of the above conditions are met and the extension is `.scss` or `.sass`, then the named Sass or SCSS file will be imported. If there is no extension, Sass will try to find a file with that name and the `.scss` or `.sass` extension and import it.

Comment: $baseFontSize is in vaiables.scss  , all my variables and @mixin are in variables.scss


with less I import variables.less first then all other import can read it , in sass I guess not

thanks for your reply but that was not my question

Answer (score 0):

Just came through with that issue at work.

Your variables files (and all partials files you have) must start with `_`.

As soon as you use `@import` in SASS, the file inside the instruction must be named `_myFileName.scss`

Hope it helps!